# Postgresql: row number changes on update

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am new to Postgresql and I am using version 9.3. I have a table in which i have a couple of rows. My question is, when I update a row, the row number is changed and it is moved to the the last location in the table. My question is: is this the default behavior, because I think when a row is updated, it should not be moved from its place? The operation seems to be like deleting and then inserting the row again.

Here is the sample SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE cities
(
    city_id serial, 
    city_name character varying(50), 
    PRIMARY KEY (city_id)
);

INSERT INTO cities (city_name) VALUES ('ABC');
INSERT INTO cities (city_name) VALUES ('DEF');
INSERT INTO cities (city_name) VALUES ('GHI');
INSERT INTO cities (city_name) VALUES ('JKL');

UPDATE cities
    SET city_name = 'XYZ'
    WHERE city_id = 1;
```

Now, on:

```
SELECT * FROM cities;
```

moves the updated row with id 1 at the last location.

```
2, DEF
3, GHI
4, JKL
1, XYZ
```

Thanks

Comment: "The operation seems to be like deleting and then inserting the row again." True, unless a HOT update is done. Other users might still see the original "order" because of their transaction settings. It all depends! A database server is not a filesystem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> *the row number is changed*

There is  no such thing as a "row number" in a relational table.

> *I think when a row is updated, it should not be moved from its place*

As a row doesn't have a "place", there is no such thing as "moving" it out of that either.

---

### Rows in a relational table are *not* sorted.

Think of them like balls in a basket.

Without an `ORDER BY` the DBMS is free to return the rows in any order it thinks is OK.

If you need to have the rows ordered in a certain way the **only** (really: the only) way to get that is to use an `ORDER BY` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, table is an unordered set *by definition*.

But PostgreSQL has an architecture feature shown below:

```
CREATE TABLE cities
(
    city_id serial, 
    city_name character varying(50), 
    PRIMARY KEY (city_id)
);

INSERT INTO cities (city_name) VALUES ('ABC');
INSERT INTO cities (city_name) VALUES ('DEF');
INSERT INTO cities (city_name) VALUES ('GHI');
INSERT INTO cities (city_name) VALUES ('JKL');

SELECT ctid, city_id, city_name FROM cities;
-- (0,1)    1   ABC
-- (0,2)    2   DEF
-- (0,3)    3   GHI
-- (0,4)    4   JKL

UPDATE cities
    SET city_name = 'XYZ'
    WHERE city_id = 1;

SELECT ctid, * FROM cities;
-- (0,2)    2   DEF
-- (0,3)    3   GHI
-- (0,4)    4   JKL
-- (0,5)    1   XYZ
```

So simplistically speaking an `UPDATE` in PostgreSQL is not much different from a `DELETE` followed by an `INSERT` or is Copy-On-Write procedure.

That is why `SELECT` result after `UPDATE` is different *by default*. And that is why PostgreSQL RDBMS has such features like tuple version, dead tuples, `VACUUM` (kind of garbage collector), Heap Only Tuples (HOT) and so on. That is why a table with single row or even without any rows in PostgreSQL can have physical size much more than expected after massive DML.

Just a feature.