# Is there any way to avoid PostgreSQL placing the updated row as the last row?

Tags: postgresql

Well, my problem is that each time that I make an update of a row, this row goes to the last place in the table. It doesn't really matter where was placed before.

I've read in this post [Postgresql: row number changes on update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26619495/postgresql-row-number-changes-on-update) that rows in a relational table are not sorted. Then, why when I execute a `select * from table;` do I always get the same order?

Anyway, I don't want to start a discussion about that, just to know if is there any way to don't let update sentence place the row in the last place.

Edit for more info:

I don't really want to get all results at all. I have programmed 2 buttons in Java, `next` and `previous` and, being still a begginer, the only way that I had to get the next or the previous row was to use `select * from table limit 1` and adding `offset num++` or `offset num--` depending of the button clicked. So, when I execute the update, I lose the initial order (insertion order).

Thanks.

Comment: There indeed is no order in a table. Of course you won't get results in *random order every time*, the system is deterministic and doesn't go out of its way to randomise the order on purpose. But if you do want ordered results, you need to explicitly order them by something; otherwise the order is not guaranteed and/or undefined.

Comment: "*Then, why when I execute a select * from table; do I always get the same order?*" - simple answer: you don't.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name The point is that I do.

Comment: @deceze I edited the post for more info that I thought could help us to find another solution.

Comment: Sooo.... `SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id LIMIT 1 OFFSET 42`...!?

Answer (score 0):

You could make some space in your tables for updates. Change the fill factor from the default 100%, no space for updates left on a page, to something less to create space for updates.

From the [manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createtable.html) (create table):

> fillfactor (integer)
>
> The fillfactor for a table is a percentage
> between 10 and 100. 100 (complete packing) is the default. When a
> smaller fillfactor is specified, INSERT operations pack table pages
> only to the indicated percentage; the remaining space on each page is
> reserved for updating rows on that page. This gives UPDATE a chance to
> place the updated copy of a row on the same page as the original,
> which is more efficient than placing it on a different page. For a
> table whose entries are never updated, complete packing is the best
> choice, but in heavily updated tables smaller fillfactors are
> appropriate. This parameter cannot be set for TOAST tables.

But without an ORDER BY in your query, there is no guarantee that a result set will be sorted the way you expect it to be sorted. No fill factor can change that.